# Are Marquees Safe to Use?

Tags: html, cross-browser, web-standards

I personally love marquees when used properly and sparingly. You don't see them a lot anymore but I think they can add some simple eye-candy to load in things like news feeds or updates etc. Since it is not part of the standards anymore is there any chance that a browser might not support the marquee tag some time in the future? Should I avoid my personal preference just to be safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt the marquee will make a comeback. I have no proof, however I can offer a replacement. Quite simply, the marquee tag wasn't all that configurable. These days web developers demand a lot more control. You can easily emulate a marquee using javascript (here's [an example](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)). So for now, my advice is if you must have a marquee, use javascript. If it makes a comeback later, it'll be trivial to switch back.

Comment: Ok, cool! According to that link css3 has some new style attributes with the marquee element also http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/

Comment: See, I told you I had no proof :) Very cool, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, there is no real threat or harm in using `<marquee>`. Clearly on this [link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee), W3C implies the "*Don't use it*" anymore scheme. No offense, but I find `<marquee>` to be some kind of cheap attention grabber, nowadays. It had its day, probably you might want to settle in using JavaScript as mandatory alternative.

Comment: "No offense, but I find <marquee> to be some kind of cheap attention grabber" - exactly.